# How do I loop over part of a variable name?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I need to use a local macro to loop over part of a variable name in Stata.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
local phth mep mibp mbp
tab lod_`phth'_BL
```

Stata will not recognize the entire variable name.

```
variable lod_mep not found
r(111);
```

If I remove the underscore after the `phth' it still does not recognize anything after the macro name.

I want to avoid using a complicated `foreach` loop.

Is there any way this can be done just using the simple macro?
Thanks!

Comment: Stata won't recognize the entire variable name simply because you have passed the entire local to the command: `tab lod_mep mibp mbp_BL`. So unless you have variables named `lod_mep`, `mibp` and `mbp_BL` this will break (in fact, it breaks with `tab` regardless because there would be 3 variables). Macros are not used to loop over the elements of the list - for that you need a loop as @Brendan Cox points out.

Comment: To be clear, the result I want is the following:

    tab lod_mep_BL
    tab lod_mibp_BL
    tab lod_mbp_BL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is a bit confusing. First, this is precisely the purpose of a loop, and second, loops in Stata are (at the "introductory level") quite simple. The following example is a bit nonsensical (and given the structure, there are easier ways of going about this), but should convey the basic idea.

```
// set up a similar variable name structure
sysuse auto , clear
rename (price mpg weight length) /// 
       (pref_base1_suff pref_base2_suff pref_base3_suff pref_base4_suff)

// define a local macro to hold the elements to loop over
local varbases = "base1 base2 base3 base4"

// refer to the items of the local macro in a loop
foreach b of local varbases {
    summ pref_`b'_suff
}
```

See `help foreach` for the syntax of `foreach`. In particular, note that the structure employed above may not even be required due to Stata's *varlist* structure (see `help varlist`). For example, continuing with the code above:

```
foreach v of varlist pref_base?_suff {
    summ `v'
}
```

The wildcard `?` takes the place of one character. `*` could be used for more flexibility. However, if your variables are not as easily identifiable using the pattern matching allowed by *varlist*, a loop as in the first example is simple enough -- four very short lines of code.

---

#### Postscript

Upon further reflection (sometimes the structure of the question anchors a certain method, when an alternative approach is more straightforward), searching the help files for information on the tabulate command (`help tabulate`) will direct you to the following syntax: `tab1 varlist [if] [in] [weight] [, tab1_options]`

Given the discussion above about the use of *varlists*, you can simply code

```
tab1 lod_m*_BL
```

assuming, of course, that there are no other variables matching the pattern for which you do *not* want to report a frequency table. Alternatively,

```
tab1 lod_mep_BL lod_mibp_BL lod_mbp_BL
```

is not much longer and does the trick, albeit without the use of any sort of wildcard or macro substitution.

Comment: Nice answer. Also note the difference between `tab` and `tab1`. The former will not work with three variables while the latter will